# Air bubbles or digitizer making contact with the LCD?

Tags: lcd, digitizer

I have a Sony SVD11 with Multitouch LCD Panel (LP116WF1) and noticed bubbles in the images below have developed over the last few months. At first it was just one small one near the base of the screen then more appeared and then two large ones on the leftmost edge which have now joined into one.

I'm trying to determine if this is the glue boiling off and creating a bubble between layers **or** if there is a space between them which is now making contact? Pressure has no effect and I wouldnt expect the panel to get that hot as its physically separate from the rest of the components and surrounded by airflow.

If appropriate I will try and find somewhere with an autoclave large enough for the panel.

[image: bubbles on low right corner]
[image: bubbles on lcd]

Comment: check the mfg date on the monitor, this might be covered by a warranty

Comment: Are you sure it isn't the packaging film that has been left on?

Comment: Had you moved the monitor prior to the issue starting? What happens if you lightly twist or flex the monitor? Do the bubbles move or diminish?

Comment: @CharlieRB Ive tried pushing, pinching, twisting and using a sucker on the front glass to pull outwards, all have no visable effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a glue problem due to manufacturing error, coupled sometimes with heat.
The big bubble is adjacent to the edge and might indicate air leaking in, but not the small bubbles. An autoclave will not help with the small bubbles, and the big bubble will need re-gluing, which is rather complicated

Pressing will not help, as at least one upper layer glued to the LCD is hard. Repairing is a time-consuming job that requires separating and replacing however many layers are glued to the LCD screen, and damage can easily happen.

Most repairmen will prefer just replacing the screen, as the above can take hours and a mistake may be fatal to the LCD. You might be able to find a cheap replacement screen on Alibaba or similar.

Comment: This makes sense. The panels Sony used for these unit were all pathetic, huge ghosting issues and some blacklight bleed. Not unlikely that QC fell down in other areas too. Unfortunately as its a glued assembly repairing usually means replacing the entire section making it very expensive. It may not be economical. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score -1):

On my nexus 9, bubbles move: they float slowly depending on orientation of screen.

Stand device on edge when not in use. Bubbles will move to top. If bubbles are on side, stand device so that edge is up.

It's kinda fun watching the bubbles move and join and separate.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).